# Python: Determine minimum value within a dictionary that contains lists/tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, spatial, min

I have the following dictionary full of city names as keys, fake coordinates stored within a tuple, and corresponding cumulative pairwise distance values. I am trying write a function that returns the dictionary items for the key with the smallest distance value, 29.550506953719747 in this case.

My dictionary:

```
d = {'Las_Vegas': ((11.0, 10.0), 31.571777946711684),
     'Los_Angeles': ((4.0, 8.0), 29.550506953719747),
     'San_Diego': ((7.0, 5.0), 32.02332325098408),
     'Seattle': ((3.0, 26.0), 57.29385852375022)}
```

Desired output:

```
'Los_Angeles': ((4.0, 8.0), 29.550506953719747)
```

Current approach:

```
min(d.items(), key = d.get)
```

This returns:

```
('Seattle', ((3.0, 26.0), 57.29385852375022))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
min(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
```

The problem with your current solution is that `d.items()` doesn't return the keys of `d`, so `d.get` always returns `None` when called, so `min` can't really do its job.

`x[1]` will get the dict value for the the key (`x[0]`) and `x[1][1]` will then access the second value of the tuple (the one you care about).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried a bunch of different combinations of indices without knowing what each index value was actually doing. I want to buy you a beer!